# PHP - if string part matches string then

Tags: php

For some reason `stripos` isn't having the desired affect I thought it should have.

What im trying to do here is if one variables contents partially match another then override that variable.

```
<?php
    $street = 'Lightbowne Road';
    $addresline1 = '284 Lightbowne Road ';
    $addresline2 = 'Lightbowne Road ';
    $addresline3 = '284 Lightbowne Road';
    $addresline4 = 'jim ';
    $addresline5 = 'Lightbowne Road';
    if (  stripos($street, $addresline1) !== false ) {
        $addresline1 = 'addresline1 ';
    }
    if (  stripos($street, $addresline2) !== false ) {
        $addresline2 = 'addresline2 ';
    }
    if (  stripos($street, $addresline3) !== false ) {
        $addresline3 = 'addresline3 ';
    }
    if (  stripos($street, $addresline4) !== false ) {
        $addresline4 = 'addresline4 ';
    }
    if (  stripos($street, $addresline5) !== false ) {
        $addresline5 = 'addresline5 ';
    }
    $addresslines = $addresline1.$addresline2.$addresline3.$addresline4.$addresline5;
    $streetcomp = trim($street.' '.$addresslines);

echo '<p><strong>street:</strong> '.$street.'</p>';
echo '<p><strong>addresline1:</strong> '.$addresline1.'</p>';
echo '<p><strong>addresline2:</strong> '.$addresline2.'</p>';
echo '<p><strong>addresline3:</strong> '.$addresline3.'</p>';
echo '<p><strong>addresline4:</strong> '.$addresline4.'</p>';
echo '<p><strong>addresline5:</strong> '.$addresline5.'</p>';
echo '<p><strong>streetcomp:</strong> '.$streetcomp.'</p>';

?>
```

So for the above code the desired output should be:

```
street: Lightbowne Road

addresline1: addresline1

addresline2: addresline12

addresline3: addresline3

addresline4: jim

addresline5: addresline5
```

but it does not it comes out as:

```
    street: Lightbowne Road

    addresline1: 284 Lightbowne Road

    addresline2: Lightbowne Road

    addresline3: 284 Lightbowne Road

    addresline4: jim

    addresline5: addresline5
```

So its basically just doing an exact match. Which we don't want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Remembering which order arguments go in PHP is like searching for a haystack in a needle

The [manual for `stripos()`](http://php.net/stripos) labels its arguments as `string $haystack , string $needle`; that is, it searches for the *second* argument in the *first* argument.

So you have your arguments the wrong way around: `if (  stripos($addresline1, $street) !== false ) {`

It works when the strings are identical because if `$a` is identical to `$b`, then `$a` contains `$b` *and* `$b` contains `$a`, so it will find it whichever way you put the parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the second pair of eyes. will accept in 10 mins

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to change the place from your two parameters in your stripos. This code will provide you the expected output.

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php

Stripos search the second parameter inside the first, not the first inside the second.

```
<?php
    $street = 'Lightbowne Road';
    $addresline1 = '284 Lightbowne Road ';
    $addresline2 = 'Lightbowne Road ';
    $addresline3 = '284 Lightbowne Road';
    $addresline4 = 'jim ';
    $addresline5 = 'Lightbowne Road';
    if (  stripos($addresline1, $street ) !== false ) {
        $addresline1 = 'addresline1 ';
    }
    if (  stripos($addresline2, $street) !== false ) {
        $addresline2 = 'addresline2 ';
    }
    if (  stripos($addresline3, $street) !== false ) {
        $addresline3 = 'addresline3 ';
    }
    if (  stripos($addresline4, $street) !== false ) {
        $addresline4 = 'addresline4 ';
    }
    if (  stripos($addresline5, $street) !== false ) {
        $addresline5 = 'addresline5 ';
    }
    $addresslines = $addresline1.$addresline2.$addresline3.$addresline4.$addresline5;
    $streetcomp = trim($street.' '.$addresslines);

echo '<p><strong>street:</strong> '.$street.'</p>';
echo '<p><strong>addresline1:</strong> '.$addresline1.'</p>';
echo '<p><strong>addresline2:</strong> '.$addresline2.'</p>';
echo '<p><strong>addresline3:</strong> '.$addresline3.'</p>';
echo '<p><strong>addresline4:</strong> '.$addresline4.'</p>';
echo '<p><strong>addresline5:</strong> '.$addresline5.'</p>';
echo '<p><strong>streetcomp:</strong> '.$streetcomp.'</p>';

?>
```